# MVVMCross how to do heavily work on another thread, do not freeze the UI?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, mvvm, dispatcher

I'm implementing a `UI` which contains a list I use the `framework MVVMCross`. To fill the list I iterate through several directorys to gather specific `XML documents`. Now I want to outsource this iterating process in a different thread do prevent the MainWindow from freezing and show a loading wheel or progress bar. If I start this function I get the `Exception` that i have to start the thread from a dispatcher thread, but I'am starting it already from a dispatcher thread, on my point of view. What I'am doing wrong ?

```
readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;


public HomeViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
{
    NavigationService = navigationService;
    _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
}

private async void StartDispatcher()
{
    BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _backgroundWorker.DoWork += _backgroundWorker_DoWork;

    Delegate action = new Action(_backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync);
    await _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    
}

private void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingProcess();
}
```

Tried several approaches to start the thread with the dispatcher, but nothing work.

Comment: just use `await Task.Run()` and do loading inside inside task ... problem also could be binding a lots of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do work in the background is:

```
private async void OnSomeTypeOfEvent()
{
    var progress = new Progress<long>(); // optional
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // optional
    try{
        var result = await Task.Run(() => DoWorkInBackground(progress, cts.Token));
        // Update the UI with the result
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException){} // ignore
    catch(Exception e){
       // handle failure
    }
    
}
private TResult DoWorkInBackground(IProgress progress, CancellationToken cancel){
    // Do background work work
}
```

Everything with Cancellation & Progress is optional, and require you to have some control that report progress and do cancellation.

What you are trying to do makes little sense. If you ask the dispatcher to run something it will run it on the UI thread, so it will still block the UI. The main intent of the dispatcher is when you are running things on a background thread, and need to run something on the UI thread. However, I would recommend the async/await pattern, since that tend to make the code easier to read and understand.

You will need to ensure that `DoWorkInBackground` is thread safe, and do not use any shared, mutable, data structures without proper synchronization. Try to keep the method "Pure" if possible.

Comment: Always if I try to start another thread or task, in this ViewModel I receive the exception: System.NotSupportedException. Of this CollectionView-Type will be no changes of the "SourceCollection" supported, if they are not from the Dispatcher-Thread.

Comment: @smeikey that is because you are trying to modify a collection used by the UI from the background thread. Your `DoWorkInBackground` need to produce a new list, with the UI collection updated after the await. I.e. ensure your worker method is "Pure" to avoid thread safety issues. If you do not know what that means I would recommend doing some more studying about multi threading and thread safety.

Comment: Okay, I understand the problem now. Always if I change a property that is used by the UI and want to get Access with another Thread it throws an exception.

Comment: @smeikey *Never change any UI object from a background thread*. That is why you want to make your method Pure, if it only takes inputs and returns result, not reading or writing *any* shared values, then the method is threadsafe by default. Objects like `IProgress` and CancellationToken are safe since they are specifically designed for this use case.